# Convert ArcGIS v 3.2 WMS Layer to 4.7

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, wms

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to display a WMS layer in ESRI's arcgis javascript library. I'm moving from v3.2 to v4.7 and I'm having some difficulty with the WMSLayer.

I have this code to display a layer in ArcGIS Javascript v3.2

```
<script> 
  var map;

  require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/WMSLayer", "esri/config", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Map, WMSLayer, esriConfig) {

      esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
      esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("fsapps.nwcg.gov");

      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "streets",
        center: [-98, 37],
        zoom: 5
      });

      var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer("https://fsapps.nwcg.gov/afm/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=conus.map&", {
        format: "png",
        visibleLayers: ['Last 24 hour fire detections']
      });

      map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
  });
</script>
```

This works perfectly but when I try this in v4.7 I get nothing.

```
<script>
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/WMSLayer",
  "esri/widgets/Legend",
  "esri/config",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, MapView,WMSLayer,Legend,esriConfig) {

  esriConfig.request.corsEnabledServers.push("fsapps.nwcg.gov");
  var layer = new WMSLayer({
    url: "https://fsapps.nwcg.gov/afm/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=conus.map&",
    imageFormat:'image/png',
    sublayers: [
      {
        name:"Last 24 hour fire detections"
      }
    ]
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: 'streets',
  });

  map.add(layer);

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-98, 37],
      zoom: 5
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: You are not doing any thing wrong as far as I can see. Your code works. What is throwing an error is your layer url for me. Replacing it with `https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service` displays everything I would expect.
If call your url in the browser direclty results in an error.

Comment: Yes. That's the weird part. I'm not getting any errors if I use the 2d map. I do however get an error if I use the 3d map. We're not planning to use the 3d map though.  Currently we've decided to hold off on the 4.7 migration.